# When using React-Virtualized AutoSizer, children not being rendered in test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-virtualized

I have a component which uses react-virtualized AutoSizer, and inside this component there is a react-virtualized List. The way it is rendered is:

```js
<AutoSizer>
  {({width, height}) => (
    <List ref={(ref) => (this.refVirtualizedList = ref)}
      width={width}
      height={height}
      playlistLoading={playlistLoading}
      playlistPlayingTrackId={playlistPlayingTrackId}
      rowCount={rowCount}
      deferredMeasurementCache={this.cellMeasurerCache}
      overscanRowCount={12}
      scrollToIndex={trackGroupToGo - 1}
      scrollToAlignment="center"
      rowHeight={this.cellMeasurerCache.rowHeight}
      updateTrackListFlag={updateTrackListFlag}
      noRowsRenderer={this.renderNoRowsResult}
      rowRenderer={this.renderTrackGroupRow}
      onRowsRendered={this.handleOnRowsRendered} />
  )}
</AutoSizer>
```

It works perfectly, but it is not working on tests. I cannot see anything inside the list, and the function `rowRenderer` is never being called. I'm using Jest and React Testing Library. When checking what's inside the component with the `logDOM` method, all I see is this:

```js
<div
  aria-label="grid"
  aria-readonly="true"
  class="ReactVirtualized__Grid ReactVirtualized__List"
  role="grid"
  style="box-sizing: border-box; direction: ltr; height: 0px; position: relative; width: 0px; will-change: transform; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;"
  tabindex="0"
/>
```

The List component is never rendered. Any ideas?

Answer (score 31):

Thanks to this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/493

All I needed to do is set up the tests to "mock" some behavior for AutoSizer:

Copying the same solution that you can find in the issue:

```js
describe("My Test", () => {
  const originalOffsetHeight = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, 'offsetHeight');
  const originalOffsetWidth = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLElement.prototype, 'offsetWidth');

  beforeAll(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'offsetHeight', { configurable: true, value: 50 });
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'offsetWidth', { configurable: true, value: 50 });
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'offsetHeight', originalOffsetHeight);
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'offsetWidth', originalOffsetWidth);
  });
  // Your tests
})
```

The List component is now being rendered!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, in your global setup, you can define the jsDom properties like so:

```
// jsDom does not implement offset* methods.  This will break tests 
// for components that use react-virtualized-auto-sizer 
// (https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/135#issuecomment-68191941)
Object.defineProperties(window.HTMLElement.prototype, {
    offsetLeft: {
        get: function () {
            return parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(this).marginLeft) || 0;
        }
    },
    offsetTop: {
        get: function () {
            return parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(this).marginTop) || 0;
        }
    },
    offsetHeight: {
        get: function () {
            return parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(this).height) || 0;
        }
    },
    offsetWidth: {
        get: function () {
            return parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(this).width) || 0;
        }
    }
});
```